I need to fix SwiftUI
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var isError = false
    
    var body: some View {
        Button {
            isError = true
        } label: {
            Text("CHMO")
                .background(Color.orange)
                .cornerRadius(10)
        }
        .confirmationDialog("are you sure", isPresented: $isError) {
            Alert(title: Text("Gooo"), message: Text("No More"), primaryButton: .default(Text("Yes")), secondaryButton: .cancel(Text("No")))
        }
        
        VStack {
            Image(systemName: "globe")
                .imageScale(.medium)
                .foregroundStyle(.brown)
            Text("Hello, world!")
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}

in this part of the code it gives an error:
.confirmationDialog("are you sure", isPresented: $isError) {
            Alert(title: Text("Gooo"), message: Text("No More"), primaryButton: .default(Text("Yes")), secondaryButton: .cancel(Text("No")))
        }


Static method 'buildExpression' requires that 'Alert' conform to 'View'


I need to understand how to work with .confirmationdialog
Fix this problem PLS

Please read How to ask, which has "Introduce the problem before you post any code"

.confirmationDialog is similar to an Alert. You cannot put an Alert in the actions closure
Replace it with
.confirmationDialog("are you sure", isPresented: $isError, titleVisibility: .visible) {
    Button("Yes") { doSomethingOnYes() }
} message: {
    Text("No More")
}

The Cancel button is for free
